Multiple MOSFETs in parallel to switch a large load
I want to switch a DC current of around 60 A, and I'd rather not use a giant clunky relay.
I have MOSFETs with 15 A max. switching capability.
Can I connect 5 of them in parallel or will something bad happen?
The load is not inductive, if that makes a difference.

MOSFET part number?

Well my question was generalized but specifically I am looking at AOD4184A which is anything from 10-50A depending on heat sink, etc.

The data sheets 13 amps continuous at 25 degC so, please explain the 15 amps.

Hi Andy, I somewhat "paraphrased" the numbers to make the question more general and clear.

@Andyaka 13A is for operation with 1in² copper PCB heat sink. With better cooling, if you can manage to keep the package at 25°C, it is rated for 50A. With extra heat sinking, 15A sounds doable.

Yes. N-Channel MOSFETs to behave nicely when paralleled. (Unlike BJTs).
Be aware that a 15 A MOSFET is only rated at 15 A when cooled to 25 degrees C and the gate is driven at the highest voltage (e.g., 10 V).
EDIT I see your comment in which you specified a AOD4184A MOSFET.
https://aosmd.com/sites/default/files/res/datasheets/AOD4184A.pdf
Yes, 5 of them in parallel will work quite nicely, even with a 5 V gate drive. Be mindful of your PCB layout so that the current is shared evenly. Drive them with a good high-current gate driver so they switch fast and simultaneously.

Thanks for your response.  What is a high-current gate driver?  I was just going to use a smaller mosfet like a IRML6244 or IRML0030 to get 5v from my 3.3v logic output.  (Or use a logic level switcher?)

https://www.google.com/search?q=mosfet+gate+driver+ic

" I was just going to use a smaller mosfet ". That will only drive in one direction. A gate driver IC will drive in both directions: turning on and turning off.

Thank you, I will read up on gate drivers.  Alternatively, what if I just used a logic-level MOSFET like IRF3708, it seems to be OK for powering 10A with just a 3v logic level? Datasheet: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf3708pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355df7cf5193c

"what if I just used a logic-level MOSFET". The AOD4184A  is a logic level MOSFET already. The point is not the gate voltage. The point is the gate turn on / turn off current. A gate driver IC can deliver 1 A pulse of current to turn on/off the MOSFET fast and safely.

I did a bit of reading on this; if I understand correctly the issue is that the gate is effectively a capacitor and only starts working after it is charged.  Is the point of a driver here to prevent race conditions where one MOSFET turns on before the others and gets all the current?   Still, the datasheet says it can tolerate 120A pulse, and if I calculate correctly, the others will activate within microseconds, so what is the problem?

". Is the point of a driver here to prevent race conditions where one MOSFET turns on before the others and gets all the current?" Yes. As well as minimizing the time when both the current and voltage are high = high power dissipation.

Yes, you can parallel them.
You don't want to run parts at their maximum rating, you want some margin, I like 50%. You should have a small copper pad heatsink for each. Something about 1 inch square.
If you are using PWM, you may need to perform additional calculations to assure that the switching dissipation is not significant.
